# Parsing json returned by foursquare for iPhone gives Unrecognised leading character

Tags: ios, json, parsing, foursquare

I'm trying to get the nearby places using the foursquare api.
Here's the json data that is returned from

```
 NSDictionary *results = [jsonString JSONValue];
 NSLog(@"%@", results);
(
        {
        code = 200;
        errorDetail = "This endpoint will stop returning groups in the future. Please use a current version, see http://bit.ly/lZx3NU.";
        errorType = deprecated;
    },
        {
        groups =         (
                        {
                items =                 (
                                        {
                        categories =                         (
                                                        {
                                icon = "https://foursquare.com/img/categories/parks_outdoors/default.png";
                                id = 4bf58dd8d48988d163941735;
                                name = Park;
                                parents =                                 (
                                    "Great Outdoors"
                                );
                                pluralName = Parks;
                                primary = 1;
                                shortName = Park;
                            }
                        );
```

Then I try to get the list of the groups in an array with

```
NSArray *groups = [ (NSDictionary *)results objectForKey:@"groups"];
```

This returns the following error

```
2011-11-05 11:42:12.907 XperienzApp[1972:207] No of results returned: 0 Results : (null)
2011-11-05 11:42:13.225 XperienzApp[1972:207] -JSONValue failed. Error trace is: (
    "Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=3 \"Unrecognised leading character\" UserInfo=0x5849cd0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Unrecognised leading character}"
)
2011-11-05 11:42:13.225 XperienzApp[1972:207] No of results returned: 0 Results : (null)
```

How should I parse this?

Edit:
I tried the suggested technique, this gives me an array

```
id groups = [[(NSDictionary *)results objectForKey:@"response"] objectForKey:@"groups"];

    if ([results count] > 1){
        NSLog(@"groups class %@\ngroups %@ %d", groups, [groups class], [groups count]);
```

The log output is of the form:

```
 {
                categories =                 (
                                        {
                        icon = "https://foursquare.com/img/categories/nightlife/danceparty.png";
                        id = 4bf58dd8d48988d11f941735;
                        name = Nightclub;
                        parents =                         (
                            "Nightlife Spots"
                        );
                        pluralName = Nightclubs;
                        primary = 1;
                        shortName = Nightclub;
                    }
                );
                contact =                 {
                };
                hereNow =                 {
                    count = 0;
                };
                id = 4eb33ba561af0dda8f673c1b;
                location =                 {
                    address = "144 Willow St 4R";
                    city = Brooklyn;
                    crossStreet = Pierrepont;
                    distance = 462;
                    lat = "40.696864";
                    lng = "-73.996409";
                    postalCode = 11201;
                    state = NY;
                };
                name = "Entertainment 720, Ltd.";
                stats =                 {
                    checkinsCount = 3;
                    tipCount = 0;
                    usersCount = 1;
                };
                verified = 0;
            }
        );
        name = Nearby;
        type = nearby;
    }
)
groups __NSArrayM 1
```

This is again not json and is hard to parse, how do I get the output in json.

Answer (score 3):

I'm the iPhone lead at foursquare. I'll try to take a stab at what's going on here.

First of all, I highly recommend you use JSONKit for your parser. It's lightweight and insanely fast: https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit

It appears that you are parsing the JSON properly and getting the dictionary properly. Then you are logging the parsed object, not the original JSON. The output you are seeing is how Objective-C chooses to serialize the parsed dictionary to text. It is definitely not JSON. Using JSONKit, you could send the JSONString selector to your parsed result and convert it back to JSON and log that.

If you could provide some details on the problem you are trying to solve, I might be able to help you out more. And as Maudicus said, please pay attention to the error you are getting back. You don't want your app to break when we make the change to the API.

Comment: Ok, I'll look at JSONKit, I'm basically trying to get a list of the nearby places that the foursquare api returns for my app.

Comment: now I'm using JSONKit, but it's hard to figure out the structure of the json returned.
NSDictionary *json_obj = [jsonString objectFromJSONString];

NSArray *results = [json_obj objectForKey:@"places"];

How do I get the names of the places from this json.

Comment: Like anoopr said, you should make sure to use the v= param so that you get the current venues API.  Once you do and pass it to JSONKit, you should be able to get an array of venues with the following: NSArray *venuesData = [[json_obj objectForKey:@"response"] objectForKey:@"venues"];

Answer (score 1):

If the output below `NSLog(@"%@", results);` is your log statement.  It appears your results variable is an array of dictionary objects.

Try to log the class of results to verify that `NSLog(@"%@", [results class]);`

If it is an array your groups object is the second object.

```
if ([results count] > 1)
id groups = [results objectAtIndex:1];
NSLog(@"groups class %@\ngroups %@", [groups class], groups);
```

Keep doing this until you understand the format of your data

Also the line

```
errorDetail = "This endpoint will stop returning groups in the future. Please use a current version, see http://bit.ly/lZx3NU.";
```

should be cause for concern.  Check the documentation on foursquare for the current way of getting groups.

Comment: I'll try this out and post back the results.